# MariaDB crashed: Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian, innodb, myisam

I've a Debian GNU/Linux 9 (4GB, 2 CPUs) on Digitalocean. Tonight (I've done nothing) my DB (mariaDB) crashed with this errors. I ran a wordpress with InnoDB and myISAM tables:

```
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 500.0M
InnoDB: mmap(549126144 bytes) failed; errno 12
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [ERROR] **Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB**
2020-10-17  0:51:18 140430430813568 [ERROR] Aborting
```

---

---

**My full DB conf:**

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 500M
max_heap_table_size     = 25M
tmp_table_size          = 25M
#log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 2M
query_cache_size        = 50M

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
#log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = exclude_database_name

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!

#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates you can use for example the GUI tool "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
#
# Accept only connections using the latest and most secure TLS protocol version.
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with OpenSSL:
# ssl-cipher=TLSv1.2
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with YaSSL (default in Debian):
# ssl=on

#
# * Character sets
#
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
#
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * Unix socket authentication plugin is built-in since 10.0.22-6
#
# Needed so the root database user can authenticate without a password but
# only when running as the unix root user.
#
# Also available for other users if required.
# See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.1 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.1]
```

Here my first page of htop
[image: htop result after some minutes]
Could not export/copy htop result.

I would be happy if you could help me out!!

Thanks a lot
M

Comment: Please post complete configuration file. And text results from complete first page of top OR htop to confirm a few capacities.  If you are using ALL MyISAM tables, drop innodb_buffer_pool_size=10M, please.

Comment: The critical error in your logs is "InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool".  Include `show global status like 'innodb_buffer_pool_pages_%'` to examine the current buffer pool page. 100% usage is ok. Work out which aspects of your current VM can be reduced in memory, or if none, get a bigger instance.

Answer (score 1):

> InnoDB: mmap(549126144 bytes) failed; errno 12

Above error seems database is not getting enough memory as per configuration. Can you stop php-fpm first then try to start database server.

Comment: Innodb is only configured to use 500MB for its buffer pool, and the htop output shows that more than 1.5GB should actually still be available. So something more weird seems to be going on. Maybe this is a NUMA server, and memory is unevenly allocated across its NUMA zones, so that one of these runs full due to this allocation?